# Unmarried Couple Splitting up with Joint Ownership of Home

Tags: mortgage, jointly-held-property

My boyfriend lived with me and my parents for 3 years. We purchased a home together. A year later, he tells me that it's over and moves in a new girlfriend with a teenager. Neither one of them work, I'm devastated and continue to pay the bills. I get lawyer and try to have him sign a document so I can refi the house in my name. He refuses, they both get jobs and he wants me to pay all of the mortgage and utilities until he can rebuild his credit (while he wasn't working, he ran up his credit card bill). He wants him and his new GF to live for free for a year. Can a judge hear this case and decide to force him to release the mortgage to me for refinance instead of going nuclear and ruining my credit? This morning he told me that he would rip my head off and threatened me, call me vindictive B..but I really just want to break all ties with this guy.

Comment: Better suited to law.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question

Comment: If he threatened you in a serious way, talk to someone experienced in domestic abuse. If you actually think he might carry out a threat, call the cops.

Comment: This is clearly a legal question and shouldn't be asked (nor answered) here.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the unmarried status, you need to see a lawyer.  Essentially you have a business with this person owning a home as the asset, and a mortgage for which you are responsible for.  A lawyer needs to examine any paperwork you have and with knowledge of your particular jurisdiction's laws can advise you on the proper course of action.

You paint a really ugly picture of this guy.  I bet you are correct that he is kind of a horrible person.  "Tough love" time:  You willingly entered into a long term contract with this person.  Why would you do such a thing?  Perhaps some self reflection and counseling is in order.  This is probably more important than worrying about your credit.

All that being said, it is good of you to want to break ties with this person.  You can rebuild.  All will be good if you concentrate on the right things.

Comment: Not only are you 'in a business', but in many jurisdictions the law will treat you as married, whether or not you actually went through a ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not married, its a partnership agreement, and unless there's a written contract, either the two of you agree on how to handle the home, or it's off to court you go.

If you were both supposed to pay for the home, and he failed to for a a while, that would put him in breach of contract which I would think gives you a good position in court.

On the other hand, if you are at all concerned about your safety from this louse, remember, he knows exactly where the house is.

Comment: I would assume if they purchased a home together, they have some form of a contract at least for that purchase.